# React Native ActionSheetIOS rendering takes a lot of time

Tags: react-native

I got a problem with react-native ActionSheetIOS. In my project i can not use react-native Picker for ios devices, so i decide to use ActionSheetIOS. But render takes a lot of time when i pass array with 200 elements inside as a options property. Maybe someone know how to improve render time of this component? Or it depends on native realization of ActionSheetIOS component?

Comment: options (array of strings)  should be a list of button titles . What are the elements that you've pass to its?

Comment: array of 200+ strings

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found any solution?